# Make scipy.optimize.minimize modify variables in-place

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am using scipy.optimize to:

- minimize an objective function `objective_func`
- over a large number of variables `x` (5 - 15 GB)
- by the `trust-constr` method.

How to make `scipy.optimize.minimize` directly modify `x` without making any copy?

Current it doesn't seem to do that.

Thanks.

Test:

Equality constraints are omitted to keep it simple.

```
import scipy.optimize as so
import numpy as np
def objective_func(x):
    return np.sum(x**2)
x = np.arange(3)
result = so.minimize(objective_func, x, 
                     method='trust-constr')
print("result:", result.x)
print("delta:", x - result.x)
```

Result:

```
result: [-1.89895546e-11 -1.89895756e-11 -1.89895364e-11]
delta: [1.89895546e-11 1.00000000e+00 2.00000000e+00]
```

Since delta is not all zeros, `so.minimize` does not modify `x` in-place.

It probably creates an internal copy of `x`.

Comment: Is that a problem? Looks to me the overhead of one extra n-vector is small.

Comment: I'm running this in a loop for many times. The whole optimization is a coordinated descent, alternating between a constrained optimization and an unconstrained optimization. Anyway, I am not using scipy.optimize at the moment now.